# Is there a tool we can use to allow users to login to Ubuntu using their Google accounts

Tags: login, google, online-accounts

We have G-Suite for our company. and all users use windows 10 & windows 7, where we installed Google Credential provider for windows @ https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gcpw/. So users can login to their windows PCs using their google accounts and we will have full control on their PCs. now today we have couple of users which will use Ubuntu . So is there equivalent tool, to GCPW for Ubuntu users?

Thanks

Comment: GCPW is Windows-only, hence the W. That said, you can use [Google’s Secure LDAP](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9048516?hl=en) service if you have an Enterprise or Educational account.

Comment: @matigo yes i know that GCPW is for windows only,, i am asking about an equivelant tool that works similarly for ubuntu..

Comment: There is Endpoint Verification ... please see https://cloud.google.com/endpoint-verification/docs/overview and https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9018161?hl=en ... also see `apt show libpam-google-authenticator` and its page https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam ... If used together, you might come very close to what you want and that might suffice.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Google isn't running when the Ubuntu sign on screen is presented to you. A global user called "GDM", for **G**nome **D**esktop **M**anager, is the only one signed on and they really aren't even signed on.

A real user must sign on with password and then you could run any program, including google, at start up. But, that defeats the spirit of the question.